# Two divs within another div overlap

Tags: html, css

I asked a similar question already but haven't found an answer. I am now at a different section of my website but have the the issue here as well. The code is super basic, so I am hoping this will help to solve the issue.

Some context: My front page is sectioned in 3 container `divs`, each of them with `100vh`, so they should take up the entire screen, even when someone resizes the browser. The second `div` in the code below (`.showcase`) should stick to the bottom of the Container `div` (that's why I added `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0`).

My issue is now that the two `divs` in the Container `div 1`, keep overlapping when I reduce the browser height for example. But I want them to 'push' each other away from each other, basically not giving space for the other `div` to overlap. So that when I, for example, would add a padding to the two `divs`, that the padding still shows on the page even if resizing the browser. And no matter what I added (`display: block`, `Flexbox`, even putting the `divs` into a `table` etc) all of this didn't help and the content of the two `divs` keeps overlapping.

Can anyone help me here? I literally don't know how to go from here...

Here is the code:

```css
.Container1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: rgb(74, 105, 113);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(74, 105, 113, 1) 0%, rgba(129, 161, 170, 1) 60%, rgba(181, 207, 214, 1) 100%);
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.hp_slogan {
  padding-top: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}

.showcase {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container1">


  <div class="hp_slogan">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

  </div>


  <div class="showcase">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: can you rephrase your question?  Do you have a sketch or two that would show what you want to do?

Comment: They are overlapping because of "position: absolute;".

Comment: @Roman you are right, when I delete position absolute from the second div, it doesn't overlap anymore but instead the content in this div just disappears now when I resize the browser. Is there a way that the text will 'move' when I reduce the browser's height but will not overlap with the other div content? And how would I position the 2nd div to stick to the bottom of the container section when I can't use position absolute?

Comment: @JanaLux I'm not sure what result you expect but display: flex for the container may help. Or you can use position: absolute; with a bottom padding for the container (in case if the showcase has a fixed heigh)

Comment: @Roman, thanks a lot! I got what I wanted with removing absolute and then using Flexbox for sticking the 2nd div to the bottom :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will solve your problem If I understood correctly what you need.

```
.Container1 {
  overflow:hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: rgb(74,105,113);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(74,105,113,1) 0%, rgba(129,161,170,1) 60%, rgba(181,207,214,1) 100%);
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.hp_slogan {
  padding-top: 20%;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}

.showcase {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

[You can simulate it in JSFiddle with this link](https://jsfiddle.net/emredmrcan/fmovu45w/6/)

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you. Used flexbox to distance two `divs`

```css
.Container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: rgb(74, 105, 113);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(74, 105, 113, 1) 0%, rgba(129, 161, 170, 1) 60%, rgba(181, 207, 214, 1) 100%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container1">


  <div class="hp_slogan">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

  </div>


  <div class="showcase">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>

</div>
```